# Uniformly random planar map

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Is there a way to sample a planar map uniformly at random? I am aware of the Cori-Vauquelin-Schaeffer bijection that can be used to sample and study uniformly random quadrangulations. There are other results in the literature that allow for sampling other classes of planar maps, but I haven't seen any results for the entire class of planar maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you may potentially be interested in :
http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~fusy/Articles/FusyAofa.pdf

Nathann

Answer (score 7):

Planar quadrangulation with $n$ faces are in bijection with planar maps with $n$ edges. The quadrangulation is bi-partite, so colour its vertices white/black. inside each face, add a diagonal edge between the two black vertices. Then delete all white vertices and incident edges. The result is a map with $n$ edges, and it is not hard to see that this is a bijection.

In fact, this is one of the reasons quadrangulations are a particularly interesting class of planar maps.

Comment: Are there methods for sampling fixing other statistics (e.g. number of vertices or number of faces)?